CKAN 2.11 Installation - ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from 'flask'
I tried to install CKAN v2.11 from the source and stumbled on to the below error.

ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from 'flask'. Is
anyone else facing the same issue?

I am using Python3.12.5.
cmd$: ckan -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan_dev.ini run

I am expecting to see the CKAN site hosted on my local machine.
